# Creating a stored function similar in behavior to AVG() or COUNT()

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to sort out how you create functions similar in behavior to how `AVG()`, `COUNT()` and other similar functions work. The issue I am having is understanding what the type of the values I am passing into the function are, and how to access the results of the query so I can perform the necessary math on the columns.

**Example:**

As an example, I want to create a function that provides me with the ratio between two columns. For instance, I would write:

`SELECT ratio(pointsRecieved, pointsPossible) FROM myTable;`

```
+----------------+----------------+
| pointsPossible | pointsRecieved |
+----------------+----------------+
|              5 |              2 |
|              3 |              3 |
|             10 |              9 |
|              7 |              6 |
|              4 |              0 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

And receive  `0.68965517241` as the function output.

Is this sort of thing possible with stored functions? If so, how do you go about doing this?

Comment: You want to define a custom aggregate function?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes! I could not figure out the appropriate terminology which was really hindering my searches. Thank you for that.

Comment: Why not just do `SELECT SUM(pointsRecieved) /  SUM(pointsPossible) FROM myTable;` ?

Comment: @IkeWalker I could do that perfect fine, however, this is something I was very curious about as a learning opportunity. Even if it is not practical.

Comment: Seams like you can only do that modifying the C source code.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell You cannot do this with a stored function. You would need to use a user defined function instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html